# How to get HTML from the browser in SWT after setting the URL

Tags: java, browser, swt

I have tried using

```
String html = browser.getText();
```

But I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to change Variant type result = -2147352571
>       at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant.getAutomation(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.getText(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.getText(Unknown Source)

I have read this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433526

Could anyone help me with other way to get HTML out of the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force SWT to use another browser engine (if available) to work around this bug.

For example

```
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.WEBKIT );
```

or

```
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.MOZILLA );
```

The source of the problem, however, is that you are trying to obtain the page source before it was fully loaded. If there wasn't the bug that you mentioned, SWT would still return an empty string.

The fix is to listen for the page to complete loading and only then ask the browser to return the page source. For example:

```
Browser browser = new Browser( shell, SWT.NONE );
browser.addProgressListener( new ProgressAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void completed( ProgressEvent event ) {
    String text = browser.getText();
    // here, text will contain the full page source
  }
} );
browser.setUrl( "http://eclipse.org" );
```

Comment: I've contributed a patch that was accepted. Thus [Bug 433526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433526) is fixed in the meanwhile and will be available in Eclipse/SWT 4.6.1 and 4.7+.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I was able to get the html content using browser.addProgressListener.

Comment: Done the answer is marked as 'accpeted'.I have a question regarding the [Bug 433526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433526) now i am not able to reproduce the bug using SWT 4.4 version the one that i used before which was causing the error.As per the comment the error was fixed for SWT 4.6.1 version right?.Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: See the _Target Milestone_ field of a bug report to see in which version the fix will be published. In this case, it is 4.6.1. That your code works with SWT 4.4 probably means that the bug was introduced at a later point in time.

Comment: Got it.Thank you for the response.